# How can I implement Audit4J in my Java GUI application

Tags: java, audit-trail, audit4j

This is my first time encountering Audit4J, and I'm wondering how I can implement that in my Java GUI project. I've tried reading the documentation in the website, but I wasn't able to grasp it concretely, and I've also seen the sample project for Audit4J in the github, but I wasn't able to understand it. Is there some other links, or can someone help me with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add audit4j-core as a dependency. If you want to save audit trails in to database you can should configure database handler in the configuration file in the classpath. Sample configuration file can be found [here](https://github.com/audit4j/audit4j-demo/blob/master/sample/audit4j.conf.yaml).

Then you'll able to submit audit event calling AuditManager. Please refer the [documentation](http://audit4j.org/documentation/#sending_events_call).

Comment: You should add all the dependencies of Audit4j. what is the build tool you using. If you are using maven, ant or gradle dependencies will automatically resolved. If the issue is not yet resolved please open a bug report.https://github.com/audit4j/audit4j-core/issues